# jQuery not properly loading a CodeIgniter view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
$("#slideshow").click(function() {
    $("#content").fadeOut(function() {
        $(this).load('<?php $this->load->view("slideshow"); ?>', function() {
            $(this).fadeIn()
        });
    });
});
```

When I run the above code in Ci, CodeIgniter pends the 'slideshow' view to the beginning of the document. I need it to only display when the id of 'slideshow' is clicked. This code snippet usually works, but idk why it's acting funny now. Any ideas?

Comment: What the heck are you doing?  What is in the `slideshow` view?

Comment: The first parameter of .load() is supposed to be a URL, not HTML or whatever you have in your view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do here.  View files in CodeIgniter are supposed to contain HTML.  The Controllers can load the views, and pass them data if need be.  Views are templates.

```
$(this).load('<div id="test"></div>', function(){});
```

This will throw an error, as `.load` expects a URL, not HTML (unless you're binding to the `onload` event, where the 1st param can be an array of data, but I don't think that's what you're doing).

What I assume you want is to have jQuery load the content of the view file into `#content`.  To do this, you're gonna need a controller that outputs the view.  For example:

*Controller*:

```
function slideshow(){
    $this->load->view('slideshow');
}
```

*jQuery*:

```
$("#slideshow").click(function() {
   $("#content").fadeOut(function() {
      $(this).load('/path/to/controller/slideshow', function() {
         $(this).fadeIn()
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby: No prob, glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

This produces such a garbage that your browser will put it somewhere (at the beginning of the document):

```
$(this).load('<?php $this->load->view("slideshow"); ?>', function() {
```

Because the string needs proper encoding, e.g. as a javascript string with [`json_encode`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/json_encode):

```
$(this).html(<?php echo json_encode($view_html); ?>);
$(this).fadeIn();
```

Check the [CI docs how you get the view returned as string](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) instead of being outputted. I leave this as an exercise.

Comment: @Rocket: An error? No idea, however I fixed the URL. Probably this needs a second `json_encode`?

Comment: `$(this).load('<div id="test"></div>', function(){});` says `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: >`.

Comment: this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#JavaScript - nevermind not all browser support that URI there, I replaced it with just `html()` which does that.

Answer (score 0):

try do it:

```
$(this).load("<?php $this->load->view('slideshow','','true'); ?>", function() { ......  }
```

Note that i use single quote, and third parameter true.